# Find a volume shown in Device Manager, but hidden in My Computer

Tags: c#

I have connected to one external hard drive, now it's showing in Drive manage, but does not show in my computer. I want to know how to use C# code to find it and display it in my computer. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a drive letter to it. Which requires a valid, formatted partition on the drive.

Use the Disk Management tool to set this up:

1. Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools
2. Open "Computer Management"
3. Select "Disk Management"
4. Right-click on the drive and either create a partition or select "Change Drive Letter".

You don't do this in C#; it does not require writing any code.